# Select from 3 possible columns, order by occurances / relevance

Tags: php, sql, database

I have a table that contains 3 **text** fields, and an ID one.

The table exists solely to get collection of ID's of posts based on relevance of a user search.

Problem is I lack the Einsteinian intellect necessary to warp the SQL continuum to get the desired results -

```
SELECT `id` FROM `wp_ss_images` WHERE `keywords` LIKE '%cute%' OR `title` LIKE '%cute%' OR `content` LIKE '%cute%'
```

- Is this really enough to get a relevant-to-least-relevant list, or is there a better way?

Minding of course databases could be up to 20k rows, I want to keep it efficient.

---

Here is an update - I've gone the fulltext route -

EXAMPLE:

```
SELECT `id` FROM `wp_ss_images` WHERE MATCH (`keywords`,`title`,`content`) AGAINST ('+cute +dog' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

However it seems to be just grabbing all entries with any of the words. How can I refine this to show relevance by occurances?

Comment: Your query won't take use of indexes. Try a *full text* search.

Comment: What are your desired results?  Are you trying to get a list of results where those that match all 3 fields show first, then those that match 2, etc. (i.e. `relevant-to-least-relevant list`)?  Your current query is returning any id where any of the fields contains the search phrase...

Comment: Thanks. Looking into it now.

Comment: @sgeddes Simply stated I just want a relevant search based on occurrences of the keyword, greatest to least.

Comment: I've just updated the original question with my progress. Still a little off - its not making a descending list of relevance. Any ideas on how to refine it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a list of results based on the relevance of the number of occurrences of keywords in each field (meaning cute appears in all three fields first, then in 2 of the fields, etc.), you could do something like this:

```
SELECT id
FROM (
  SELECT id, 
    (keywords LIKE '%cute%') + (title LIKE '%cute%') + (content LIKE '%cute%') total 
  FROM wp_ss_images
  ) t
WHERE total > 0
ORDER BY total DESC
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/65bccd/3)

Comment: I went with this one. Thanks a lot. Its great.

Answer (score 0):

You could concatenate the fields which will be better than searching them individually

```
SELECT `id` FROM `wp_ss_images` WHERE CONCAT(`keywords`,`title`,`content`) LIKE '%cute%'
```

This doesn't help with the 'greatest to least' part of your question though.